# Magento Backorders not working in the Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, inventory, backorder

I have "Allow Backorders" enabled in `System/Configuration/Inventory`. 
If the product has stock `qty = 1` (for example), it can be ordered in any quantity via checkout, but when I try to add more than 1 of this item to order in admin, I have an error:
The requested quantity for "XXX XXX XXX" is not available.

Magento: 1.9.3.2

Comment: Have you set the option to "Allow QTY below 0?"

Answer (score 0):

First, of you need to configure at system config level as you did.

You need to confirm same setting for already created product. So go that product and double check that setting.